# Configuring php with nginx inside a reactjs app

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean

I have a nginx configuration for a react app.  I however would also like to include a sitemap.php that I build dynamically with php.

So here is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mysite.com;

    index index.html index.htm;


    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }


    location /sitemap.xml {
        alias /var/www/web-app/public/sitemap.php;
    }


    location / {
        root /var/www/web-app/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        default_type "text/html";
    }

}
```

The snippets file consist of this:

```
# regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

# Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

# Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
# see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
```

Also, this is hosted on an Ubuntu 16.04 digitalocean VPS.

My react app still loads fine.  It is based on the index.html in my site root (/var/www/web-app/public).  If I put test.php in the public folder, I get a 404 error.  For my sitemap.xml alias, it forwards correctly to sitemap.php (also in public) but the php does not render.

So my two biggest issues here:
1.  Why am I getting a 404 on /mysite.com/test.php?
2.  And why is my php not rendering when it does work? (i.e. sitemap.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `root` statement for your `location ~ \.php$` block, so your PHP files will not be found. As this seems to be a common `root` with the `location /` block, simply move the statement up to `server` block scope:

```
root /var/www/web-app/public;

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    default_type "text/html";
}
```

There are a number of ways to redirect `/sitemap.xml` to `/sitemap.php`, but a `rewrite...last` will be simplest and invisible to users:

```
location = /sitemap.xml {
    rewrite ^ /sitemap.php last;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for `location` syntax, and [this one](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for the `rewrite` directive.

Comment: Thank you.  That answered both questions and you gave me bonus information on how to properly rewrite.